# updating associated model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am confused how to best update data from an associated model in rails with an angular front end (although this is more of a rails issue really).

Say I have a model called votable which some attributes (start_date, end_Date) and has_many texts (descriptions of the votable in different languages)

```
class Votable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votable_texts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :votable_texts
end
```

The show method in my controller generates json data that I use in angular to build the form:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { 
      render :json => @votable.to_json(
        :except => [:created_at, :updated_at],
        :include => {
          :votable_texts => { 
            :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]
          }
        } 
      ) 
    }
  end
end
```

This generates something like the following json:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "start_date": "2015-02-05T00:00:00.000Z",
  "end_date": "2016-02-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "votable_texts": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "votable_id": 2,
      "locale": "nl",
      "issue": "Test"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "votable_id": 2,
      "locale": "en",
      "issue": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

On the angular side I read this json into a variable and use ng-model for binding this data to my form. When the user hits the save button I use $http.put to post this data back to rails (in the same structure as the json generated by rails).

The thing is that the attributes of the votable model do get updated (for example start_date), but those that are in the nested votable_texts model are not updated.

The relevant pieces of the controller look like this:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @votable.update(votable_params)
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @votable }
    else
      format.json { render json: @votable.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private 

def votable_params
  params.permit(:id, :start_date, :end_date, :votable_texts)
end
```

What am I missing? Do I need to handle the updates of the association myself manually? How is this best done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is because you need to permit the nested parameters of the `votable_texts` model. However when using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `update` Rails is going to expect you to pass `voteable_texts_attributes` in order for it to update the associated records. In this case you would have the following.

`params.permit(:id, :start_date, :end_date, votable_texts_attributes: [:id, :voteable_id, :locale, :issue])`

So you may need to update the show action to use `voteable_texts_attributes` or if not you're going to have to change the param key somewhere along the line.